# Случайно удалила модуль из проекта android studio, как вернуть?

Tags: android-studio, проект

Случайно удалила импортированный модуль из структуры проекта, на скриншоте выделила кнопку красным. Теперь он отображается только в Project. Как теперь вернуть её обратно, чтобы программа опять видела её модулем? Помогите пожалуйста[image: Красным выделена папка, которую удалила из модулей]

Comment: Так там же нажмите на `+` и добавьте новый модуль

Comment: Он не дает заново добавить этот модуль.